# How to Register a conventional Interface in Autofac

Tags: autofac

I have an autofac DI in my project. 
I want to expose an interface by conventional which all other interfaces of my project will inherit from. Is it possible to automatically register the components of the inherited interfaces at start up level? For example:

```
Public interface IConvetionInterface {}
public interface IImplementationA:IConvetionInterface 
{
public void DoSomethingA();
}

public interface IImplementationB:IConvetionInterface 
{
public void DoSomethingB();
}
```

Injecting through constructor;

```
public class ConsumerA
    {
        private readonly IImplementationA _a;

        public DealerRepository(IImplementationA A)
        {
            _a= A;
        }

        public Act()
        {
            _a.DoSomethingA();


        }

    }
```

How do I  register `IConvetionInterface`  to  make all its dependencies resolve in Autofac.

Comment: what do you mean by automatic , without doing anything like registering of the component on application start ?

Comment: Thanks Prashant. That is the question i am asking. How do we register such interface and its dependencies at  the startup level?

Comment: what you found is the way to go for any DI container or autofac , thought you don't want to register at all on application start, good you found the solution happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to come up with this solution by using autofac Assembly Scanning Configuration as provided in their documentation page [Autofac Documentation Page](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html#scanning-for-types)

I have an open generic interface

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
    { }
```

Implemented by

```
public class Repository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : RepositoryBase<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>{}
```

Then, I created an empty interface

```
public interface IConventionDependency
    {

    }
```

This method was called to register my components at startup level:

```
public static void RegisterAPSComponents(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<APSContext>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<,>)).As(typeof(IRepository<,>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();




  builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IConventionDependency).Assembly).AssignableTo<IConventionDependency>().As<IConventionDependency>().AsImplementedInterfaces().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();



        }
```

By the above registration, any interface that inherits from IConventionDependency will be registered automatically in the container.

example: 
 create an interface:

```
public interface IDealerRepository : IConventionDependency
    {
        List<Dealers> GetDealers();
    }
```

then Implement the interface :

```
public class DealerRepository : IDealerRepository
    {
        private readonly IRepository<VTBDealer, int> _repository;

        public DealerRepository(IRepository<VTBDealer, int> repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public List<Dealers> GetDealers()
        {
            return _repository.GetAllList().MapTo<List<Dealers>>();


        }

    }
```

in conclusion, without explicitly registering `IDealerRepository`, it gets resolved in MVC Controller constructor.